# Underlying C*Algebra operators in standard quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Linearity in standard quantum mechanics (QM) is the key to making the math possible in this field, but the presence of nonlinear operators in QM is what is more generally dealt with. Working with the [Generalized Uncertainty Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), certain nonlinear terms appear and affect calculations. Are these nonlinear terms compatible or similar to the [C*Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) operators used in quantum mechanical calculations?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the "generalized uncertainty principle"? Just the standard Robertson-Schrödinger uncertainty for arbitrary operators. What are the "nonlinear terms" you are concerned about? C*-algebras are linear spaces - they don't contain nonlinear operators.